# table in the middle of the page

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, positioning

I'm creating an Appendix of lots of tables. I write

```
\newpage  
\section{Appendix}  
\label{append}  
\begin{table}[h]  
\input{table1}  
\caption['Tis table1]{'Tis table1}  
\label{table1}  
\end{table}
```

This starts a page with heading ``Appendix'', and then table 1 just after the heading on the top of the page.

I want a page with heading ``Appendix'', and then **table 1 below the heading in the middle of the page**.

If any help, I also tried

```
\begin{table}[p]
```

but this starts a page with heading ``Appendix'', and another page with table 1 in the middle of the page..

I'd appreciate any and all help. Thank you very much!

Best,

John

Comment: Drop `\begin{table}...\end{table}` and use `\captionof{table}{your caption}` (requires `caption` package however)

Comment: Which document class are you using?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for your reply. I tried, but it awkwardly stretches the table to fit the page, which does not look normal (relative to other tables which follow)..

Comment: @Mico I'm using documentclass puthesis, which is my university's dissertation template!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See, if the following can help you:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\newpage
\section{Appendix}
\label{append}

\vfill
\begin{table}[htb]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption['Tis table1]{'Tis table1}
\label{table1}
\end{table}

\vfill
\clearpage
next page

\end{document}
```

I assume, that you use `book` (or `report`) document class. Instead of table I use `example-image` to simulate it.

[image]

**Addendum:**
The very the same result is obtained with table too:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\section{Appendix}
\label{append}

\vfill
\begin{table}[htb]
    \caption['Tis table1]{'Tis table1}
\label{table1}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}
    \hline
aaaaaaaaaaaaa   &   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb   \\   
aaaaaaaaaaaaa   &   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb   \\
aaaaaaaaaaaaa   &   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb   \\
aaaaaaaaaaaaa   &   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb   \\
aaaaaaaaaaaaa   &   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb   \\
aaaaaaaaaaaaa   &   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb   \\
aaaaaaaaaaaaa   &   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb   \\
aaaaaaaaaaaaa   &   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb   \\
aaaaaaaaaaaaa   &   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb   \\
    \hline
aaaaaaaaaaaaa   &   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb   \\
aaaaaaaaaaaaa   &   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb   \\
aaaaaaaaaaaaa   &   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb   \\
aaaaaaaaaaaaa   &   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb   \\
aaaaaaaaaaaaa   &   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb   \\
aaaaaaaaaaaaa   &   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb   \\
aaaaaaaaaaaaa   &   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb   \\
aaaaaaaaaaaaa   &   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb   \\
aaaaaaaaaaaaa   &   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb   \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\vfill
\clearpage
next page

\end{document}
```

[image]

So,if you can not obtain the above result with your table, than you have something very different from this case. If you will add it in your question, I will be able to test my MWE with it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I changed  
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}  
to
\input{table1}
and tried your suggestion. Unfortunately, it puts the table at the bottom of the page. If you have further suggestions, I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: I don't see any reason that with table is different result than with image. I will check with some my dummy table.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i didn't input properly.. i finally submitted my dissertation with your help; thank you so much!

Comment: The most important is, that you submitted your thesis (dissertation) .-) and hopefully learn something about latex too.